# how to force stop and execute a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I run this code I get a promise, the data never gets inserted into my db, i cant use await since its not a top level function eg: `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.`

if i log `todaysMatches.create(game);` i get `Promise { <pending> }`

```
async function getTodaysMatches(){

    let response = await axios({ // I CAN USE AWAIT HERE -> TOP LEVEL FUNCTION
        method: "get",
        url: "https://api.football-data.org/v4/matches",
        headers: {
            "X-Auth-Token" : "API-KEY"
        }
    })
    
    todaysMatches.deleteMany({}).exec();
    matches = response.data.matches;
    matches.forEach(match => {
        
        const game = {
            areaName: match.area.name,
            areaCode: match.area.code,
            areaEmblem: match.area.flag,
            competitionName: match.competition.name,
            competitionCode: match.competition.code,
            competitionEmblem: match.competition.emblem,
            seasonStartDate: match.season.startDate,
            seasonEndDate: match.season.endDate,
            utcDate: match.utcDate,
            status: match.status,
            stage: match.stage,
            group: match.group,
        
            homeTeam: {
                name: match.homeTeam.name,
                emblem: match.homeTeam.crest,
            },
        
            awayTeam: {
                name: match.awayTeam.name,
                emblem: match.awayTeam.crest,
            },
        
            score: {
        
                winner: match.score.winner,
                duration: match.score.duration,
        
                fullTime: {
                    home: match.score.fullTime.home,
                    away: match.score.fullTime.away,
                },
                halfTime: {
                    home: match.score.halfTime.home,
                    away: match.score.halfTime.away,
                },
        
            },
            referees: {
                name: match.referees.name,
                nationality: match.referees.nationality,
            }
        }

            todaysMatches.create(game); // PROBLEM CODE HERE


    });
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use await inside foreach because it's a function but when you use a while or for loop to loop through your data you can use await so it forces the code to execute which eliminates any promises

```
async function getMatches(){

let response = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://api.football-data.org/v4/competitions/PL/matches",
    headers :{
        "X-Auth-Token" : "API-KEY"
    }

})

await allMatches.deleteMany({}).exec();
match = response.data.matches;
let i = 0;

while (i < match.length){
    const game = {
        areaName: match[i].area.name,
        areaCode: match[i].area.code,
        areaEmblem: match[i].area.flag,
        competitionName: match[i].competition.name,
        competitionCode: match[i].competition.code,
        competitionEmblem: match[i].competition.emblem,
        seasonStartDate: match[i].season.startDate,
        seasonEndDate: match[i].season.endDate,
        utcDate: match[i].utcDate,
        status: match[i].status,
        stage: match[i].stage,
        group: match[i].group,
    
        homeTeam: {
            name: match[i].homeTeam.name,
            emblem: match[i].homeTeam.crest,
        },
    
        awayTeam: {
            name: match[i].awayTeam.name,
            emblem: match[i].awayTeam.crest,
        },
    
        score: {
    
            winner: match[i].score.winner,
            duration: match[i].score.duration,
    
            fullTime: {
                home: match[i].score.fullTime.home,
                away: match[i].score.fullTime.away,
            },
            halfTime: {
                home: match[i].score.halfTime.home,
                away: match[i].score.halfTime.away,
            },
    
        },
        referees: {
            name: match[i].referees.name,
            nationality: match[i].referees.nationality,
        }
    }
        await todaysMatches.create(game);
        i++;
}
```

};